# Can easycap viewer work on macOS?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have recently bought an EasyCAP DC60. I have also downloaded easy cap viewer Fushicai on my MacBook Air which is currently running macOS Sierra. I'm trying to display my PS3 on my laptop using a HDMI to AV converter because I don't have an AV cable for my PS3. When I start up the easy cap viewer, it just shows a black screen.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you share links to the actual _Fushicai_ viewer you downloaded and the HDMI to AV converter you're using?

Comment: Yes, the download link is https://bentrask.com/easycap/EasyCapViewer-fushicai.zip and the converter I'm using is called "Mini HDMI2AV".

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that EasyCapViewer 0.6.2 isn't supported on versions of macOS above Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10). In other words, it will work with versions of the Mac OS from OS X Leopard (specifically 10.5.8) up to Yosemite, but won't work on El Capitan or Sierra.

According to the developer:

> 2015-10-31: Reports indicate EasyCapViewer doesn't work on OS X El
>   Capitan. This would be a good time for other developers to pitch in. I
>   will spend some time investigating too but no guarantees.

Source: https://bentrask.com/easycap/

Unfortunately there has not been an update since from the Developer.

In the absence of other macOS alternatives, you may have some joy from using a Windows installation via [Bootcamp](https://www.apple.com/au/support/bootcamp/) or via software such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/au/products/desktop/), or [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html).

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on Yosemite/Mavericks and works good for the video , there is no audio but that is easy to grab and mix it with LightWorks it works good 4 me I have a ton of old VHS that I need to digitize before the tapes go bad.... just create a VM with either Yosemite or Mavericks and try it there.